# how do immigration of some country check your travel history for migration verification?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens

I was in uae from 2008 to 2010 and have unpaid loan. The local bank is not willing to settle at a common ground hence i left it as it is. I had a loan with an international bank which i negotiated and settled without any problem. Anyways my question is, my wife is in australia and she is gonna apply for a partner visa upon her work permit. My uae visa was on my old passport and now i have a new passport which was issued last year. I have clean record in india hence my pcc and character will not be an issue here... What about UAE? I ll certainly not show my old passport to the australian embassy as it has my previous travel details with visa. Will that make any problem for me as they wud expect pcc from uae as well. Please advise.

Comment: Your question feels like you are hiding something. How come you have several loans which you did not pay back in full? A bit of debt which a bank refuses to settle is one thing but if you have been involved in several bankruptcies or repeatedly contracted debt you didn't intend to pay back, that could be an issue. Also, you won't submit the passport with the UAE visa in it but do you plan to lie about living there? You are very likely to be asked about where you lived and the more you try to hide, the more likely you are to be found out and to have no way to ever get an Australian visa.

Answer (score 2):

Some countries require e.g. criminal records from all the places you have resided in the last X years. That would be the most important thing to satisfy the “good character” requirement. There will also typically be an interview, where contradictions could create problems for you. A few countries might also share data on things like immigration violations but that's not very common and I would be surprised if the UAE and Australia did. In that context, criminal convictions are the most relevant, it's not obvious that some unpaid private debt would necessarily stop you from getting a visa.

But if your question is whether you can successfully get a visa, residence permit or even citizenship in one country when you have some past immigration violations, debt or even criminal conviction at the other end of the world, the answer is yes. Even if some of this might in fact disqualify you for some visas in some countries and there are procedures to vet applications, there is no global system that would ensure each and every country has direct access to all the relevant information.

On the other hand, if your plan is to lie about your being in the UAE at all, you need to realize this is quite risky. If you are found out (and many things can betray you: Are you planning to create a fictional employment history? What about the web?), your credibility will be durably damaged, not by the outstanding loan itself but by your attempt at obtaining a visa fraudulently.